# What does `that's why we free` mean

Tags: phrases, expressions, quotes

I got this quote from Ali movie said by Bundini:

> God don't care about you. Don't care about me. In all of everything,
>   we don't mean nothing. He don't owe us. We be. That's the onliest thing
>   he did. But that's good. That's why we free. But free ain't easy. Free
>   is real and real is a motherfucker. It eats raw meat. It walk in its
>   own shoes. It don't ever waiver. Yeah

I don't really understand what it means *That's why **we free**.* I was thinking that it probably should be *we **are** free*, but subtitles seems to be correct on all other dialogs so I believe it's correct here as well.

Comment: I shall never forget, partly because of the sheer horror of the situation and partly because I'm interested in language, a survivor of hurricane Katrina saying on the radio: "My wife - she gone." I should imagine that the answer to your question is that that is how some Americans (?) speak. Being interested in language, I would say a more interesting question is: given there doesn't appear to be a verb in either sentence, when someone says "That's why we free." or "My wife - she gone.", what's actually going on under the bonnet (the hood).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [African American Vernacular English](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152323/african-american-vernacular-english)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ali is speaking in the English dialect AAVE (African-American Vernacular English, sometimes called 'Ebonics'), in which the verb 'to be' is dropped in the present tense. You can indeed understand it correctly as '*we are free*'.

Comment: I think this is a typo considering the fact that other be verbs were not dropped elsewhere. Also, you should note that there are always multiple typos in movie scripts. I see so many typos in the Ali script that I can't even count them.

Comment: I don't see any reason for assuming it is a typo. The other instances of present "be" are "that's" (twice), "ain't", and "Free is real and real is a motherfucker". I can quite believe that "that's" is in free variation with "that", the negative is required for "ain't", and the third is a rhetorical sentence which might lack the impact with the repeated "is". v

Comment: @ColinFine You can find the script and read it. You will know why I assumed it is a typo. You can hear the part at 1:48:54 and I clearly hear **'re**. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rBJJVvaJ0gc